# HTML form request body empty - NodeJs

Tags: html, node.js, forms, postman

I was tring to create an API POST using Node.js and express. I was just trying to post some data using html form:

```
<form id="myform" action="http://localhost:4000/add" method="post" enctype="application/json">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

The server would just receive the POST request and display the body into console.log.

```
router.post('/add', function (req, res){
    console.log("request: "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
})
```

What is being received at the console is:
request: {}

Trying to post into the same api using Postman - raw, JSON(application/JSON), things work fine.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: The question is previously asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers do not support submitting HTML forms as application/json. Most browsers would probably ignore the value and send the form as the default `enctype` which is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. To parse that, you'd need to use an appropriate middleware. One such example is the `body-parser` module's [`urlencoded()` middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).

Comment: Great! Thanks, solved my problem: I just added `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` additional to the json body-parser i already had.

Answer (score 0):

In **action** attribute you don't need to specific the host just specify path such as "**/add**".

Comment: That's only true, if you call from the same server (so e.g. if html-file is alsoon localhost).